# Android Studio eliminar elemento de Recycler View

Tags: android, sqlite

Estoy tratando de eliminar elementos de un Recycler View, que los cargo dandolos de alta en una Base de Datos SQLite. Al seleccionar el boton "Borrar" me borra el registro de la base de datos SQLite, hasta ahi todo bien, pero no me borra el elemento en sí del Recycler View.

Este es mi método eliminar() creado en mi clase BaseDeDatos:

```
    public String eliminar(String Nombre){
    String mensaje ="";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int cantidad = db.delete("pets", "nombre='" + Nombre + "'", null);
    if (cantidad != 0){
        mensaje = "Eliminado correctamente";
    }
    else{
        mensaje = "No hay registros que eliminar";
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

Y ésto es lo que hace mi boton "Borrar" en mi clase RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
            bnBorrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BaseDeDatos db = new BaseDeDatos(context);
                String Nombre = nombre.getText().toString();
                String mensaje = db.eliminar(Nombre);
                Toast.makeText(context, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Para ser más claro, dejo una imagen de un elemento cargado en mi RecyclerView, el cual debería desaparecer al apretar el Boton "BORRAR":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

**EDITADO**

Recycler Class:

```
public class RecyclerViewEnganche extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewEnganche.ViewHolder>  {
private ArrayList<PetsActivity> mExampleList;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
List<PetsActivity> data;

public void update(ArrayList<PetsActivity> datas){
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(datas);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface OnItemClickListener extends View.OnClickListener {
    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) { mListener = (OnItemClickListener) listener; }

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    public TextView nombre, edad, raza, alergia;
    public String id, reserva;
    public Button bnCuidados, bnBorrar;
    Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View v, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();
        nombre = v.findViewById(R.id.tveNombre);
        edad = v.findViewById(R.id.tveEdad);
        raza = v.findViewById(R.id.tveRaza);
        alergia = v.findViewById(R.id.tveAlergia);

        bnCuidados = v.findViewById(R.id.bnCuidados);
        bnBorrar = v.findViewById(R.id.bnBorrar);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onDeleteClick(position);
                    }
                }

            }

        });
    }


    void setOnClickListeners() {

        bnCuidados.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ElegirCuidados.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                intent.putExtra("reserva", reserva);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        bnBorrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BaseDeDatos db = new BaseDeDatos(context);
                String Nombre = nombre.getText().toString();
                String mensaje = db.eliminar(Nombre);
                Toast.makeText(context, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}

public List<Pets> listaPets;

public RecyclerViewEnganche(List<Pets> listaPets) {
    this.listaPets = listaPets;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itempets,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view, null);
    // view.setOnClickListener(this);

    return new ViewHolder(view, null);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nombre.setText(listaPets.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.edad.setText("Edad: " + listaPets.get(position).getEdad());
    holder.raza.setText("Raza: " + listaPets.get(position).getRaza());
    holder.alergia.setText("Alergias: " + listaPets.get(position).getAlergia());
    holder.reserva = listaPets.get(position).getReserva();
    holder.setOnClickListeners();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaPets.size();
}
```

}

Main Class:

```
public class PetsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewEnganche enganchePet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pets);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvPets);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    BaseDeDatos tablaPets = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext());

    enganchePet = new RecyclerViewEnganche(tablaPets.mostrarPets());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(enganchePet);

    enganchePet.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewEnganche.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
            removeItem(position);
        }
    });
}

private void removeItem(int position) {
    enganchePet.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

}

Comment: has probado mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: no, eso como lo implemento?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez es decir, cuando apreto BORRAR, lo saca de la base de datos, y si vuelvo atras y luego adelante, ya no está el elemento, pero la idea sería que al apretar BORRAR directamente desaparezca el mismo, sin tener que ir hacia atras y volver a la activity. Hay alguna manera para actualizar la activity al apretar el boton de BORRAR?

Comment: si pero tenes que decirle a tu recicler view que los datos han cambiado

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez eso lo intenté, ahí edité la publicación subiendo mi clase Recycler y mi clase Main donde muestro el RecyclerView, intenté de esa manera pero no me funcionó, que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu adapter tienes tu arreglo `public List<Pets> listaPets;`
Ese arreglo es el que estas pintando en tu `RecyclerView`. Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es borrar el elemento de la `BD` y tambien eliminar ese elemento de `listaPets`. Una vez que hayas borrado de ambos lados, tienes que notificar a la interfaz de usuario que se actualize.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    BaseDeDatos db = new BaseDeDatos(context);
    String Nombre = nombre.getText().toString();
    String mensaje = db.eliminar(Nombre);
    if(mensaje=="Eliminado correctamente"){
        for(int i=0;i<listaPets.size();i++){
             if(listaPets.get(i).getNombre()==Nombre){
                   listaPets.remove(i);
                   break;
             }
        }
        //enganchePet.notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Como nota, existe el metodo `notifyItemRemoved`. A ese metodo le tienes que mandar el indice del item que eliminaste. En terminos de performance es mejor que un `notifyDataSetChanged` ya que con el `notifyItemRemoved` android solo actualiza ese segmento de informacion y con el `notifyDataSetChanged` vuelve a cargar toda la informacion.

Comment: gracias por responder @YorchSircam entiendo lo que me decis, pero no puedo aplicarlo porque el onClick que me brindaste vos lo tengo en mi clase RecyclerAdapter y el enganchePet lo tengo en mi Mainactivity

Comment: Error mio jeje, entonces en ese caso, solo mandas a llamar a notifyDataSetChanged, ya que es un metodo propio del adapter, no necesitas tener otra referencia. Modifico el codigo para que quede claro.

Comment: muchas gracias!! me funcionó a la perfección!!